# "The connection was reset" after starting my server

Tags: node.js, docker, webpack, docker-compose, webpack-dev-server

I have set up Webpack Dev Server which works fine when I start it (`yarn run webpack-dev-server`): I can visit http://localhost:3000 and see my app.

However, I've also set up Docker compose to run this server, among others, in a Docker container. When I start the Docker container, I can call `wget http://localhost:3000` in the container just fine and receive a successful response. However, when I visit http://localhost:3000 in my browser, I see "The connection was reset".

My `docker-compose.yml` does include the following line:

```
ports:
  - "3000:3000"
```

Is there anything else I forgot to do that is needed to successfully access the server from outside the Docker container?

Comment: The Webpack dev server by default binds to `localhost`, which in Docker land means it’s inaccessible outside the current container.  In addition to the command-line option in the linked answer, the Webpack documentation also has a permanent configuration setting.

Comment: Huh, thanks for that David - so much for my searching-fu. That was indeed the issue.